# Microsoft Bing Search API

Tags: c#, bing, bing-search

I am looking into the Microsoft Bing Search API as I am having a requirement to fetch the company website based on the company name.

For example : let my search query be "Microsoft", I want the API to return me the company website as "Microsoft.com".

While using Web search in the Bing Search API, the results contains many results and there is no proximity score by which I can pick the top match.What changes I can make to my query structure to accomplish this?

Does Microsoft have a Company API as well from which we can fetch the company data based on the Company Name?

Answer (score 0):

First off, specifying `responseFilter=Webpages` will help a bit.

It does not look like Bing offers a company-specific API at this time. That said, you can train your interfaces to tailor the `rankingResponse` field in the JSON response returned to you. Thereby increasing the likelihood that a company's website is the first link returned to you when you search for its name.

The way you do this is by utilizing a consistent `X-MSEdge-ClientID`, and then following the correct return-links which can usually be identified by their `displayUrl` field in the JSON response. Do this enough times, and entering a company name should return their website as the top-result each time.

You can find more/better info on how to use the `X-MSEdge-ClientID` header here:

[Bing Web Search Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn760794.aspx#Headers)